# Unable to connect to Kofax Desktop Automation Service after restart of the server

Tags: .net, kofax, kapow

Unable to connect to Desktop Automation Service after restart of the server.

Error from the Call Desktop Automation Robot action. Exception: DeviceIssue. Failed to connect. Error calling Desktop Automation Service: Caught exception. Address IP: a connect or send request failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time.(ETIMEDOUT_kapowhub) Original error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
Stack: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT IP:Port at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1129:14). Location: "Initiate Session Action" - "Connect to SAP"

Restarted the server and try to run the bot from Management Console.

Once the Desktop Automation Service is turned on, then the connection is seemless